# wicket 8 ModalWindow return value

Tags: nullpointerexception, wicket

I have a problem with the Wicket 8 ModalWindow return value, I refer to [Modal window](http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/modal-window?1), and it works fine.
I added a PageableListView to the instance (see [Pageables Example](http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/pageables?3)) and it works fine.
In order to use DATABASE data, I use IModel to perform data query. I don’t set the query conditions on the home page, and they all work normally.
However, when I pass the value back to PageableListView through the modal window, a NullPointerException will appear in the modal window.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code
ListModalTab.java

```
public class ListModalTab extends BasePage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@SpringBean
private TabHService oTabHService_;
private PageableListView cTabHListView_;

public ListModalTab() {
    final Form cForm = new Form("form");
    final Label result;

    cForm.add(result = new Label("result", new PropertyModel<>(this, "result")));
    result.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    final ModalWindow modal1;
    cForm.add(modal1 = new ModalWindow("modal1"));

    modal1.setCookieName("modal-1");

    modal1.setPageCreator(() -> new QueryModalTab(ListModalTab.this.getPageReference(), modal1));
    modal1.setWindowClosedCallback(target -> target.add(cForm));
    modal1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    modal1.setCloseButtonCallback(target -> {
        setResult("Modal window 1 - close button");
        return true;
    });

    cForm.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("showModal1") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            modal1.show(target);

        }
    });

    final WebMarkupContainer cContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("container");
    cContainer.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    cForm.add(cContainer);

    /*
     * Data query using IModel
     */
    TabH oConstraintEntity = new TabH();
    IModel mTabHListViewModel = new Model() {
        public java.io.Serializable getObject() {
            return (Serializable) oTabHService_.queryByTabH(oConstraintEntity);
        }
    };

    /*
     * Use string array data
     */

    //final String[] names = { "Doe, John", "Presley, Elvis", "Presly, Priscilla",
    //        "Hasselhoff, David", "Moore, Demi", };

/*
 *  PageableListView is working properly if used with string array
 */

//  PageableListView<String> listview = new PageableListView<String>("rows", Arrays.asList(names), 1) {
//        @Override
//        protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
//          item.add(new Label("tabId", item.getModelObject()));
//        }
//    };

/*
 *  If the PageableListView is passed in using an IModel Object, the modal window will have a NullPointerException.
 */
    PageableListView<TabH> listview = new PageableListView<TabH>("rows", mTabHListViewModel, 1) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<TabH> item)    {
            final TabH oTabH = (TabH) item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("tabId", oTabH.getTabId()));
        }
};

cContainer.add(listview);

cContainer.add(new AjaxPagingNavigator("navigator", listview));
    this.add(cForm);
}

/**
 * @return the result
 */
public String getResult() {
    return result;
}

/**
 * @param result
 *            the result to set
 */
public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

private String result;}
```

QueryModalTab.java

```
public class QueryModalTab extends WebPage {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private TabH tabH = new TabH();

public QueryModalTab(final PageReference modalWindowPage, final ModalWindow window) {

    CompoundPropertyModel mTabH = new CompoundPropertyModel(tabH);
    Form cForm = new Form("form", mTabH);

    TextField cTabId = new TextField("tabId");
    cForm.add(cTabId);

    TextField cTabName = new TextField("tabName");
    cForm.add(cTabName);

    cForm.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("closeOK") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (modalWindowPage != null)
                ((ListModalTab) modalWindowPage.getPage()).setResult("Modal window 1 - close link OK");
            window.close(target);
        }

    });

    /*
     *  NullPointerException appears in ((ListModalTab) modalWindowPage.getPage())
     */
    AjaxSubmitLink cConfirm = new AjaxSubmitLink("confirm") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            super.onSubmit(target);

            if (modalWindowPage != null)
                ((ListModalTab) modalWindowPage.getPage()).setResult(tabH.getTabId());
            ModalWindow.closeCurrent(target);

        }

    };
    cForm.add(cConfirm);

    cForm.add(new AjaxLink<Void>("closeCancel") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if (modalWindowPage != null)
                ((ListModalTab) modalWindowPage.getPage()).setResult("Modal window 1 - close link Cancel");
            window.close(target);
        }
    });

    this.add(cForm);
}
}
```

NullPointerException

```
Root cause:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.web.webpage.systempage.tab.QueryModalTab$2.onSubmit(QueryModalTab.java:52)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:223)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1251)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:946)
 at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:770)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:176)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:151)
 at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:598)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:306)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:280)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:222)
 at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:208)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:912)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:65)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:283)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:253)
 at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:221)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:262)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:204)
 at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:286)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please attach the stacktrace.

Comment: Insetad of going the route of using `getPage()` and casting it, why don't you just pass the `IModel<String> result` to your QueryModalTab and set the Model Object using that.